# Android 2-dimensional Array and arraylist best practice?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I was wondering if anyone could answer my fairly noobish question of which is better practice to use when programming.

i know to make a 2 dimension array i can either use:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

or

```
String[][] myArray2;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using ArrayList in the manner in which you showed is completely fine. However, only use Array list if you really need your array to grow and shrink at run time. IF you're not sure that you need the array to grow or shrink, then go ahead and just use the ArrayList to start. If you don't need the array to be dynamic, you should go with String[][]. String[][] cannot grow or shrink in size after it has been allocated though.

If your application is performance intensive, I strongly suggest trying to write the app such that String[][] is used. More importantly, try to avoid a lot of string manipulation because this will cause a lot of allocations (and thus garbage collections). If you can use a CharBuffer[][] instead, you will be able to avoid object allocations. Again though, if you're writing a simple app, and it doesn't matter all that much that your app allocates (and thus eventually causes garbage collections), going with the ArrayList makes things easier to handle.

Since you consider yourself a noob, you might want to just go ahead and start with the ArrayList because it's a little easier to deal with.

Also, this isn't really much of an Android question, just more of a Java question.

Comment: Cheers Andi, by your explnation i might have to use the ArrayList method.
Basically the application is a rss feed reader, but im saving a list of rss feeds into a textfile and loading its contents into a global array which the users should be allowed to add and remove items from the list.
im still unsure if this is the best way as i could run into problems  when i try to delete a specific rss feed from the textfile! e.g. the first rss feed when there are 5 registered.

Answer (score 0):

Since Lists can increase in size, they are the optimal solution if you are unsure, how big your 2 dimensional data strucute will be. If you know how big the structure will be, then use the normal array instead, so the little overhead what the List objects would cause wont be a problem.